# Onchange picklist value not showing dependent picklist values

Tags: visualforce, html, inputfield, selectlist, table

I am working on dependent picklist. I have a parent object on select Parent record in the first picklist I need to get all related child record in the 2nd picklist. This is working fine. But when I use other field along with this inside the  tag this picklist is not working in on change. I am confused why it is not working as expected. Please find my code below and help me!

```
<apex:page standardController="Main_Task_Configuration__c" extensions="Task_ConfigurationExtension"
sidebar="false" title="Main Task Configuration Page">

<head>

    <apex:slds />

    <style>
    #customers {
      font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }

    #customers td, #customers th {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      padding: 8px;
    }

    #customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

    #customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

    #customers th {
      padding-top: 12px;
      padding-bottom: 12px;
      text-align: left;
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
    }
</style>
</head>

<script>
    function removeRow(i) {

        var r = confirm("Are you sure to delete?");

        if (r == true) {

            removeRow1(i);

        }

    }

</script>

<apex:form id="frm"> 

    <apex:pageMessages /> 
        <div>
        <legend id="newaccountform" class="slds-text-heading--medium slds-p-vertical--medium " style="text-align:center;font-weight: 600;">New Main Task Configuration</legend>
        <legend id="newaccountform" class="slds-text-heading--medium slds-p-vertical--medium" style="background-color:lightblue !important;line-height: 0.25;">Main Task Configuration Edit</legend>
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer" Style='margin-top:5px;' id="mainTaskConfig" rendered="{!isNew}" collapsible="false" width="100%">
             <tr>
                <td class="slds-truncate" style="width:8%;padding-left: 120px;">Product</td>
                <td style="width:8%">
                    <div class="slds-select_container">
                          <apex:selectList value="{!selectProdId}" multiselect="false" styleClass="slds-select slds-form-element__control"
                                    size="1">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!RecordList}"/>
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="a"/>
                        </apex:selectList>     
                    </div>
                </td>

                     <td class="slds-truncate" style="width:8%;padding-left: 120px;">Task Type</td>
                     <td>
                        <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!selectTaskTypeId}" id="a" multiselect="false" styleClass="slds-select slds-form-element__control"> 
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!TaskTypeList}"/>
                        </apex:selectList> 
                    </td> 

            </tr> 

        </table>
        <apex:commandButton value="Render Sub Tasks" action="{!renderSubTasks}" rendered="{!isNew}"
                            reRender="frm" status="status" styleClass="slds-button slds-button_brand"
                            style="margin-left:0px"/>
        </div>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Till above code it is working fine but as soon as I am adding a inputfield it stopped working.

```
<apex:page standardController="Main_Task_Configuration__c" extensions="Task_ConfigurationExtension"
sidebar="false" title="Main Task Configuration Page">

<head>

    <apex:slds />

    <style>
    #customers {
      font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }

    #customers td, #customers th {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      padding: 8px;
    }

    #customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

    #customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

    #customers th {
      padding-top: 12px;
      padding-bottom: 12px;
      text-align: left;
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
    }
</style>
</head>

<script>
    function removeRow(i) {

        var r = confirm("Are you sure to delete?");

        if (r == true) {

            removeRow1(i);

        }

    }

</script>

<apex:form id="frm"> 

    <apex:pageMessages /> 
        <div>
        <legend id="newaccountform" class="slds-text-heading--medium slds-p-vertical--medium " style="text-align:center;font-weight: 600;">New Main Task Configuration</legend>
        <legend id="newaccountform" class="slds-text-heading--medium slds-p-vertical--medium" style="background-color:lightblue !important;line-height: 0.25;">Main Task Configuration Edit</legend>
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer" Style='margin-top:5px;' id="mainTaskConfig" rendered="{!isNew}" collapsible="false" width="100%">
             <tr>
                <td class="slds-truncate" style="width:8%;padding-left: 120px;">Product</td>
                <td style="width:8%">
                    <div class="slds-select_container">
                          <apex:selectList value="{!selectProdId}" multiselect="false" styleClass="slds-select slds-form-element__control"
                                    size="1">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!RecordList}"/>
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="a"/>
                        </apex:selectList>     
                    </div>
                </td>

                     <td class="slds-truncate" style="width:8%;padding-left: 120px;">Task Type</td>
                     <td>
                        <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!selectTaskTypeId}" id="a" multiselect="false" styleClass="slds-select slds-form-element__control"> 
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!TaskTypeList}"/>
                        </apex:selectList> 
                    </td> 

            </tr> 

        </table>
        <apex:commandButton value="Render Sub Tasks" action="{!renderSubTasks}" rendered="{!isNew}"
                            reRender="frm" status="status" styleClass="slds-button slds-button_brand"
                            style="margin-left:0px"/>
        </div>

                **<apex:inputField value="{!mainTaskConfig .Task_Name1__c}" required="true" styleClass="slds-input" />**

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I have tried inside the  outside the , nothing worked.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

```
/* Product List */
public List<SelectOption> getRecordList(){
   system.debug('***---'+selectProdId);
    prodList=[Select id, name from Product__c];
    system.debug('product'+prodList);
    List < SelectOption > options = new List < SelectOption > ();
    options.add(new SelectOption('---Select--- ' ,'---Select---'));
    for(Product__c pd:prodList){
        options.add(new SelectOption(pd.Id, pd.Name)); 
    }

    return options;
}  


/* Task Type */
public List<SelectOption> getTaskTypeList(){

    system.debug('***---'+selectProdId);

    List < SelectOption > options = new List < SelectOption > ();
    takList=[Select id, name, Task_Type_Name__c, Product__c,Product__r.name From Task_Type__c where Product__r.id=:selectProdId];
    system.debug('tasklist'+takList);
    options.add(new SelectOption('---Select--- ','---Select---'));
    for(Task_Type__c t:takList){
        options.add(new SelectOption(t.Id, t.Name));
        system.debug('under forloop'+t);
    }

    return options;
}
```

Please help me in this!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the Standard Controller in the `apex:inputField`. I think this below line.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!mainTaskConfig .Task_Name1__c}" required="true" styleClass="slds-input" />
```

need to be modified with this one. Also there is a extra spece need to be removed.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Main_Task_Configuration__c.Task_Name1__c}" required="true" styleClass="slds-input" />
```

Comment: I am not missing Standard Controller. I have removed the spaces still not working.

Comment: @RAHULSRIVASTAVA Can you please post your Apex controller as well.